# How to get Share Intent callback result

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using this method to call share my feed data:

```
    public void shareFeed() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUB");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"), 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and here's my onActivityResult code but I got data every time null in either success or fail :

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        }
    }
}
```

I want to perform call web-service after success so I need the share intent callback result.

Comment: You are calling startActivityForResult on some activity you need to show what you are filling to send it nack in activity result

Comment: It depends weather the app you opened sends result back or not.

Answer (score 13):

`ACTION_SEND` does not return any form of result. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND):

> Output: nothing

There is no point in using `startActivityForResult()`, and you will not get a result.

On API Level 22 (Android 5.1) and higher devices, you are welcome to use the `createChooser()` variant that takes an `IntentSender` as a parameter. This will let you know what choice the user made out of the chooser. However:

- That will not tell you if the user sent anything
- I do not think that you find out anything if the user just abandons the chooser (though you might interpret the absence of a choice as indicating abandonment)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) for ACTION_SEND indicates that is generates no output (ie: generates no result).